# SharePoint list not transferring "all day event"

Tags: list, calendar

I've created a custom list to add the rule of the day to my Sharepoint calendar that includes "All Day Event" as a column header and then "Yes" in each entry but the start time/end time still transfers to each calendar event. I am using 12:00AM and 11:59PM for each entry. Example: start time 1/1/23 12:00 AM and end time 1/1/23 11:59 PM. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So you don't want start time and end time in your case?

Comment: That's correct. I only need the event to transfer as 'all day'.